# How do I append an array of Strings to an array of AnyObjects in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have an array that for the sake of the example can hold both Ints and Strings, so I'm calling it an array of AnyObjects.

If I have an array of Strings, and an array of Ints, how do I put those in with the existing array of AnyObjects? (To be clear I want it to be a one-level, flat array, not with nested arrays within the array or anything).

For example, this code produces an error:

```
var arr: [AnyObject] = []

let foo = ["one", "two"]
let bar = [1, 2]

arr += foo
```

The error being "Binary operator += cannot be applied to operands of type [String] and [AnyObject]".

What should I be doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set foo and bar to [AnyObject]. If you do not then swift assumes you have [String] and [Int] arrays.

```
var arr: [AnyObject] = []

let foo: [AnyObject] = ["one", "two"]
let bar: [AnyObject] = [1, 2]

arr += foo
arr += bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `foo` to a `[AnyObject]` instead of allowing it to default to `[String]`

```
let foo: [AnyObject] = ["one", "two"]
```